# How to click a <input type="range"> at specific Position javascript

Tags: javascript, input, google-chrome-extension, click, progress-bar

I'm currently writing a Chrome Plugin for a Webpage with a video player. The chrome Plugin can already pause and play the video but I can't get it to work for pressing the progressbar. I'm guessing I'd have to click the input element at a specific position?

Input Slider

```html
<input type="range" step=".01" min="0" max="100" value="0" is="emby-slider" class="videoOsdPositionSlider emby-slider" data-embyslider="true">
```

My Javascript (Clicking the Slider and the Pause button)

```js
var input_slider = document.getElementsByClassName("videoOsdPositionSlider")[0];

console.log(input_slider.position);

input_slider.click();

var pause_button = document.getElementsByClassName("videoOsd-btnPause")[0];

console.log(pause_button);

pause_button.click();
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to skip forward in the video with javascript, like from 5:00 to 7:00. Changing the value of the progressbar doesnt change anything, when I press the progressbar with my mouse a script of the website is called, can I simulate a mouse click like that?

Comment: Try to set the input's value and then dispatch a **change** event. Something like this: `input_slider.value = 10; input_slider.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`.